# Programmatically erase iPhone's data swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, reset, erase

I am developing an iPhone Application to wipe all data from iPhone including photos, videos, contacts, messages, apps, etc. programmatically. I wish to achieve this with an iPhone Application only.

The approach I am thinking of somehow I manage to Clear data from iPhone and rewrite the memory with some junk files or binary data 1010 say. (Its just an idea!)

All I have managed to do is delete photos from Photos which are further not deleted from Recently deleted folder in Photos App.

Also, I found this [Programmatically How to wipe out iPhone or iPad data in i phone apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32179842/programmatically-how-to-wipe-out-iphone-or-ipad-data-in-i-phone-apps) in i phone apps which declines it's feasibilty.

But, Is there a way to programatically restore my iphone to factory settings? says using the C files mentioned here https://github.com/lite/osxrce/blob/master/resetapp/main.m can may be make it possible. They say they tried it on a jailbroken device though.

Comment: You can not delete all data of another app but you can delete within your app data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are hoping to do isn't possible on an non-jailbroken iPhone. You will be violating the iOS sandboxing among other things.

A similar outcome may be possible by creating your own MDM server, and building your app to interface with it. On first installation of your app, you can have it install the MDM profile. The app can then feature your 'Wipe' button which can signal to the MDM to send a wipe push notification to the device.

It would take a lot more work that what you're asking about, but it *should* be possible.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/enterprise/documentation/MDM-Protocol-Reference.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Apple do not allow to delete files which aren't created or part of your application, so you will not be able to delete data of other apps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're allowed to do that anyway. Even if you were able to do it, it would not be accepted on the app store.

Answer (score 0):

You can backup the iPhone via `AppleMobileBackup.exe -b`, then modify the according 
database file(such as addresscontacts, messages), and restore the modified `ituensbackup` files to the iPhone via `AppleMobileBackup.exe -r`.